# How can I use low-level functions (not imread) to read a grayscale image?

Tags: image, matlab, file-io, grayscale, image-formats

I'm trying to use low-level functions (`fopen` and `fread`) to read a grayscale image of type `uint16` in TIFF format as follows:

```
fid = fopen(filepath,'r');
img = fread(fid,[ncolms, nrows], 'uint16=>uint16')';
```

The obtained image matrix is different from that obtained by simply using `imread`:

```
img = imread(filepath);
```

The resulting images are shown below (the left is by `fread` and the right is by `imread`):

[image]

In addition to the obvious intensity difference, one may also note that `fread` image has some artifacts in the top edge of image. I think this must be due to their different mechanisms of reading images.

I want to know how to use such low-level functions as `fopen` and `fread` to read images (grayscale, not binary), equivalently to using `imread`, if they can.

Comment: I don't mean to sound pushy, but you've asked quite a few questions without [accepting any answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). You don't *have* to, mind you, but if an answer has genuinely helped and addressed your question, it's nice to.

Answer (score 1):

Those "artifacts" you're seeing are likely the header and tag data stored in the file before the image data. I would suggest taking a look at this [TIFF File Format Summary](http://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/egff.htm). It will tell you exactly how to read all this extra information, if you *really* want to do it yourself. Note that some of this extra tag information (i.e. ImageHeight, ImageWidth, BitsPerSample, SamplesPerPixel, etc.) will be useful in determining exactly how to read the image data correctly, and thus match the image you get from the [`imread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html) function.